# Passport, Bcryptjs, Async/Await: verify function passes any input in password as true

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, passport.js, asynchronous-javascript

Everything in my passport-local strategy seems to be working, except the verifyCallback, where the truthiness evaluation of the `validatesPassword` function returns true regardless. The problem could stem from the fact that `validatesPassword` is an asynchronous function and the `Promise {<pending>}` output while the function works out of order isn't false:

from **passwordUtils** file:

```
async function validatesPassword(passwordInput, dbHash) {
    let comparedInput = await bcrypt.compare(passwordInput, dbHash)

    //console.log("this is whats returned from compared Input " + comparedInput)
    return comparedInput;
}
```

The console.log call in `validatesPassword` normally prints *after* the conditional statement in the passport verifyCallback() function in my passport file is called:

```
 User.findOne(email)
        .then((dbResponse) => {
            //console.log(dbResponse[0][0]);
            let user = dbResponse[0][0];
            if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
            //no error, but also no user 

            const isValid = validatesPassword(password, user.hash);
            //const isValid = false;
            if (isValid) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            done(err);
        });
}


const strategy = new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passReqToCallback: true }, verifyCallback);
passport.use(strategy)
...
```

As seen above, the only way I can derive false from the aforementioned conditional is explicitly setting `isValid` to *false*. What would be the best way to get the conditional to wait for the password compare (`validatesPassword`) function and evaluate its returned boolean function? Should I promisify `validatesPassword` and add the conditional inside (I've tried implementing this on my own to no avail) of that function and pass all of that to the `verifyCallback` function in my passport file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validatesPassword()` is an `async` function.  As such it ALWAYS returns a promise.

So, when you do this:

```
        const isValid = validatesPassword(password, user.hash);
        if (isValid) {
          // ...
        }
```

That will always be truthy because `isValid` is a promise so `if (isValid)` will always pass.  Instead, you have to get the value out of the promise with either `.then()` or `await` such as:

```
        const isValid = await validatesPassword(password, user.hash);
        if (isValid) {
          // ...
        }
```

To use `await` there, you will have to make the parent function `async`.

---

Using `.then()` and combining into the code you show in your question, it can look like this:

```
User.findOne(email).then((dbResponse) => {
    let user = dbResponse[0][0];
    if (!user) { 
        return done(null, false); 
    }
    return validatesPassword(password, user.hash).then(isValid => {
        done(null, isValid ? user : false);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    done(err);
});
```

Keep in mind a couple things about the use of `async` and `await`:

1. An `async` function always returns a promise.
2. It returns that promise when the `async` function hits the first `await` and the execution of that `async` function is suspended at that point, but it returns the promise immediately and execution of the calling code that receives that promise continues.
3. Sometime later when the internal promise you are using `await` with resolves, then the function that was previously suspended at the `await` will resume executing.
4. When you eventually get to a return value in that function such as your `return comparedInput;`, that return value will then be the resolved value of the promise that was previously returned from the `async` function.  So, while this looks like a synchronous return value, it's not.  Because the function is `async`, the return value becomes the resolved value of the promise it returns.
5. The caller then must use either `await` or `.then()` to get the resolved value from the promise.

Comment: I posted my solution, would appreciate if you took a look and told me what you think if you can.

Comment: @DeltaFlyer - I added a new version to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

jfriend00's response got the wheels spinning in my head though I wasn't sure I understood at first. I looked up using conditionals in promises and conditionals that rely on promises and came up with this solution where I .then()'d `validatesPassword` and then added a conditional within that:

```
...
User.findOne(email)
        .then((dbResponse) => {
            //console.log(dbResponse[0][0]);
            let user = dbResponse[0][0];
            if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
            //no error, but also no user 
            console.log(
                `
                here's the dbResponse Object:
                user: ${user.username},
                password: ${user.hash},   
                `
            );

            validatesPassword(password, user.hash)
                .then((isValid) => {
                    if (isValid) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false);
                    }
                })
                //const isValid = false;


        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            done(err);
        });
}
...
```

I'm not sure if that's what jfriend00 was suggesting but this solution seems to work.

Comment: Look at what I added to my answer.  What you have here is mostly OK.  One thing you are missing is if `validatesPassword()` rejects, you don't handle that rejection.  I've returned that promise so a rejection will get caught at the higher level `.catch()`.  Letting rejections propagate up can simplify the catching of errors.